# Como implementar ajax con django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

Intento implementar `ajax` con `django` y me sale el siguiente error en la consola del navegador

```
500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

En ocaciones en la cmd me devuelve este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en otras solo me sale esto donde si me ejecuta la función pero igual en el navegador sale el error 500

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente codigo de html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     function recomienda(id){
        var id_evento=id
        $.ajax({
            data: {'id':id_evento},
            url: '/sugerencias-distributivo/',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
......
......

    <a href="" onclick="recomienda('{{ Evento.id }}')" class="btn btn-info">recomendar</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  apps.agenda.models import Evento


class sugerencias(TemplateView):
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

    event = Evento.objects.get(pk=request.GET['id'])
    data = serializers.serialize('json', event,fields=('Fecha','Inicio'))

    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^sugerencias-distributivo/$', sugerencias.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 1):

yo utilizaría la biblioteca simplejson:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
...
json_response = simplejson.dumps({ 'event':event, ... })                                

return HttpResponse(json_response,content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: La librería mencionada por [Antonio J. Contreras](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13358/antonio-j-contreras) puede descargarse [aquí](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).